# sh: identify: command not found imagemagick rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick-6.7.4 with rails 3 and also installed the `paperclip` gem to my application. I followed [this guide](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx) to install `imagemagick` and it works from my terminal but not with my rails app. I have included the path for the identify command in my development.rb as

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path]='/path-where-my-identify-got-installed/'
```

but it still gives me an error as

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h'/var/folders/Cd/CdjXsnlyEPyFqs4pwH83T++++TI/-Tmp-/stream20120104-2402-5iizym-0.png[0]'[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError: Could not run the `identify` command. 
Please installImageMagick.>Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/Cd/CdjXsnlyEPyFqs4pwH83T++++TI/-Tmp-/stream20120104-2402-5iizym-0.png[0]'[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError: Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.>SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try making symlink to identify from your directory to usr/bin directory.

```
ln -s /your/imagemagick/path/identify /usr/bin/identify
```

Comment: Or add `/your/imagemagick/path` to `$PATH` (however you'd do that in the context of a Rails app).

Comment: thank you so much for your response now things works fine for me with a change now my identity path is  Paperclip.options[:command_path]="/opt/local/bin/" but previously i have installed it inside my home folder i am not sure whether this made the difference but it works now