# Rails CarrierWave versions are not created for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, carrierwave, homebrew

I have the following file uploader

```
class ItemImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url
    asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "image.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end

  def cache_dir
      "uploads/tmp"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [80,80]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
```

Picture class

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
  mount_uploader :image, ItemImageUploader
  process_in_background :image
  validates_presence_of :image

  def copy
    Picture.new(:image => self.image)
  end
```

And the following config in carrier_wave.rb initialization file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.enable_processing = true
    #config.permissions = 0666
    #config.directory_permissions = 0777
    config.storage = :file
end
```

Images uploaded properly, but no thumbnails created, no errors occurred. Please advise.

Comment: @prusswan no, I have gem `"mini_magick"` and `gem 'carrierwave'` and `gem "devise"` and `gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder'`. Do I need to have something else?

Comment: I believe `mini_magick` is only a wrapper. If you read the documentation [here](https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick) you can see this at the bottom: You must have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed.

Comment: @prusswan thanks, I've already installed imagemagic via homebrew command, but still have the same behavior. Is there any way to verify whether imagemagic works properly?

Comment: `-bash: identify: command not found` Looks like there is a problem with the installation...

Comment: I don't use the mac often, but check the output of `brew info imagemagick`, and consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723506/sh-identify-command-not-found-imagemagick-rails-3)

Comment: @prusswan appreciate your help. I've installed and verified imagemagick installation. Do I need to run imagemagick server/service separately? Or CarrierWave will communicate with it automatically? (I still see the same problem - no thumbnails generated)

Comment: carrierwave should already have access to imagemagick as it is, if there's something else that is causing the problem, you will need to take a closer look at the logs and look for anything that may suggest something is missing or not found etc, and use `debugger`

Comment: I faced same problem and once I have commented process_in_background :image , in my model, Carrierwave worked well to generate versions. it seems there are some problem in 'carrierwave_backgrounder' gem

Answer (score 3):

Just hit my head against this one myself.  As the comments suggest, using `carrierwave_backgrounder` causes this problem.  You can see it in their [documentation](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder#background-options):

process_in_background - `This stores the original file with no processing/versioning.`

Doesn't help with a solution, but I thought I'd verify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a couple of hours today, because I had the same issue. Uploading of the original version would work, but it was not resized. It was working locally, but not on my production machine. Hope someone with the same issues stumbles on this answer and saves some time.

Turned out that my version of ImageMagick was not build with the correct delegates, this was the output of `$ convert -version`:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-10 Q16 x86_64 2015-08-01 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): zlib
```

I used this answer to install the delegates and build a fresh version of ImageMagick: [ImageMagick missing decode delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709488/imagemagick-missing-decode-delegates/15803403#15803403)

After that, pulled up the ImageMagick info with `$ convert -version`:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-10 Q16 x86_64 2015-08-01 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype gvc jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

And now I'm rollin'!